# 彼は、自分の信ずるところはあくまでも信じ、使命感を増幅させることを自分につねに求めていた。

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 彼は、自分の信ずるところはあくまでも信じ、使命感を増幅させることを自分につねに求めていた。

Question: What is the function/meaning of ことを here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こと itself doesn't have meaning in here. It makes verbs into noun. For example, 本を読むことが何よりも大好きだ means I love reading books more than anything. So こと makes the verb 本を読む(read books) into noun "reading books". I hope it makes sense.